# Google maps api 2 does not cache

Tags: android, google-maps, caching

I used Gmaps API 2 for my app, everything works good exept caching. It's so wierd but the Google Maps only cache correctly in speceific time!! For example in the morning everthing is ok and it caches but at the night you need to use a proxy (like droidVPN) to cache...!

- And is there any trick to precache Google Maps data legally?
- Can I copy my application maps data that cached in my device to another device?
  Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Google map caches data automatically, but not sure if it is saved for future use.

If you want to cache maps effectively, 
Take a look at [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/).

For offline map,
Take a look at [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).